# How to replace characters which not on the list

Tags: regex, oracle

I have list of valid characters which allowed to be on extract file. I need to replace all other characters with space  my oracle SQL statement.
Valid characters are

```
  'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 
  'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' 'I' 'J' 'K' 'L' 'M' 'N' 'O' 'P' 
  'Q' 'R' 'S' 'T' 'U' 'V' 'W' 'X' 'Y' 'Z' 'a' 'b' 
  'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 
  'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z' 
  '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '0' '/' '-' 
  '(' ')' '.' ',' '{' '}' '-' '?' ':'   “  ’  “
```

I’m trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE for negative lookup, it’s not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did my answer does what you want? If yes the accept it so it could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to acheive your goal is using regexp_instr instead of regexp_replace, and using a case around it that returns a space character in case it returns 0.
The downside of this solution is that you have to go over every character in the string seperately, which can be time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select regexp_replace('A12A6/6gj/-().,{}-?:“''“!@#$%^&*()_+= ' , '[^A-Z,a-z,0-9,/,-,(,),.,\,,{,},-,?,:,“,\’]'  ,  ' ') from dual

Output
A12A6/6gj/ ().,{} ?:“ “        ()
```

Add any other character inside second parameter of regexp_replace (inside `[]`) if I missed any.